# php sql code, foreach warning

Tags: php, foreach

I have the following code, not written bymyself, but I am wondering if you could spot anything wrong with it?

```
$query =    "SELECT * from #__properties_type where published = 1 AND parent =        ".$Category_id." OR parent = 0";

$db->setQuery( $query );                

$types = $db->loadObjectList();

$nP = count($types);

$mitems[0]->id=0;

$mitems[0]->name='Type';

    foreach ( $types as $item ) {

        $mitems[] = $item;

    }
```

It seems to work fine but sometimes I will see a random Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in etc/etc/etc/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `loadObjectList` function seems to return a non-array sometimes, maybe when the SQL query fails.

Quick fix:

```
if (is_array($types))
foreach ( $types as $item ) {

        $mitems[] = $item;

    }
```

but you should look for the deeper cause why the function fails, and handle the error accordingly if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

It probably means your `$types` variable isn't being set.
This will set a PHP warning off.

Comment: Is there a way to fix that? I found some reference online saying this warning can be stopped as such: " You can prevent this error by type-casting the foreach variable as an array type using "(array)" before the array variable name.
"

Answer (score 0):

Unless `$mitems[0]` is predefined before your code snippet, there's no way PHP can know about `$mitems[0]` contains an object, hence `$mitems[0]->id` will throw an warning.

To solve this:

```
$mitems[0] = new YourObject();
$mitems[0]->id=0;
$mitems[0]->name='Type';
```